# Replace data by median if they go beyond three sigma in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Here part of the data set:

```
w=structure(list(price = c(6250L, 9860L, 14690L, 34350L, 4480L, 
23230L, 14785L, 14785L, 6270L, 11530L, 26080L, 208333L, 42920L, 
10080L, 45500L, 5798L, 18400L, 5285L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
```

I want to find values which are outside 3 sigma (-3; 3)
and when any values are outside of 3 sigma, replace it with the median.

```
sapply(w, function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), (x, na.rm=TRUE)))
```

is not working for me.

How can I find any values outside of 3 sigma and replace it with the median?

Comment: can you post your desired output

Comment: They go three sigma from where exactly? The mean or the median?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try

```
within(
  w,
  price <- replace(
    price,
    abs(mean(price) - price) > 3 * sd(price),
    median(price)
  )
)
```

such that

```
     price
1   6250.0
2   9860.0
3  14690.0
4  34350.0
5   4480.0
6  23230.0
7  14785.0
8  14785.0
9   6270.0
10 11530.0
11 26080.0
12 14737.5
13 42920.0
14 10080.0
15 45500.0
16  5798.0
17 18400.0
18  5285.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
med <- median(w$price, na.rm = TRUE)
w$price[w$price < mean(w$price, na.rm = TRUE) - 3*sd(w$price) | w$price > mean(w$price, na.rm = TRUE) + 3*sd(w$price)] <- med
w
```

Comment: 1. The 3 sigma rule (of thumb) is about distance to the mean. 2. Replacing extreme values with the median is usually something that shouldn't be done and isn't even necessary.

Comment: Thanks for this precise explanation

Answer (score 1):

```
p <- w$price
m <- median(p)
replace(p, p > m + 3*sd(p) | p < m-3*sd(p), m)
```